# Dynamic Data and Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have gotten a form of the array to work it seems, though something is still showing up as wrong when I go to submit the data. Here is my store function:

```
public function store(Shipment $request)
{

    $this->validate(request(), [

        'pro_number' => 'required',
        'shipment_origin' => 'required'

    ]);

    $user_id = Auth::id();

    $input = $request->all();

    //Save Initial Shipment Data
    $shipment = new Shipment();
    $shipment->pro_number = request('pro_number');
    $shipment->shipment_origin = request('shipment_origin');
    $shipment->date = request('date');
    $shipment->due_date = request('due_date');
    $shipment->tractor_id = request('tractor_id');
    $shipment->trailer_id = request('trailer_id');
    $shipment->driver_id = request('driver_id');
    $shipment->notes = request('notes');
    $shipment->shipper_no = request('shipper_no');
    $shipment->ship_to = request('ship_to');
    $shipment->ship_from = request('ship_from');
    $shipment->bill_to = request('bill_to');
    $shipment->bill_type = request('bill_type');
    $shipment->load_date = request('load_date');
    $shipment->shipment_status = 0;
    $shipment->created_by = $user_id;

    $shipment->save();

    //Save Shipment Details
    $data = array();
        foreach ($request->get('shipment_details') as $shipmentDetails){
            $shipmentDetails = new Shipment_Detail(); //Added this recently
                $piecesNumber = $shipmentDetails['piecesNumber'];
                $piecesType = $shipmentDetails['piecesType'];
                $rateType = $shipmentDetails['rateType'];
                $charge = $shipmentDetails['charge'];
                $weight = $shipmentDetails['weight'];
                $hazmat = $shipmentDetails['hazmat'];
                $description = $shipmentDetails['description'];

    $shipment->shipment_details()->save($shipment_detail);
        }
    //Return to Register
    return redirect('/shipments');

}
```

But whenever I go to save it, I get the following response:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in ...\truckin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 131

I believe the error originates somewhere in my saving of shipment_details, though I'm not entirely certain where. It's likely I'm just overlooking something simple, this is new territory to me and I haven't quite gotten a grasp of this stuff yet.

### Update

See below for the POST data from the debugger page in case that helps:

```
_token  

"vrTs9ilq6TjZeOBL9SUjVjBtIHOxEKNfZgAO1YxM"

shipment_origin     

"1"

pro_number  

"212"

date    

"2017-11-24"

due_date    

"2017-12-24"

bill_to     

"1"

ship_to     

"1"

ship_from   

"4"

bill_type   

"1"

shipper_no  

"2122"

load_date   

"2017-11-24"

driver_id   

"1"

tractor_id  

"1"

trailer_id  

"2"

shipment_details    

array:7 [▼
  "piecesNumber" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
  ]
  "piecesType" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
  ]
  "rateType" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "1"
  ]
  "weight" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1100"
    1 => "120"
  ]
  "hazmat" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "0"
    1 => "0"
  ]
  "description" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "desc1"
    1 => "desc2"
  ]
  "charge" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1.00"
    1 => "2.00"
  ]
]

fuel_rate_type  

""

fuel_rate_amount    

""

fuel_rate_total     

""

permit_rate_type    

""

permit_rate_amount  

""

permit_rate_total   

""

other_rate_description  

""

other_rate_amount   

""

other_rate_total    

""

notes   

"notes"

comments    

""
```

### Update

The reference to the `Grammar::columnize()` comes from the following function that comes with Laravel:

```
public function columnize(array $columns)
{
    return implode(', ', array_map([$this, 'wrap'], $columns));
}
```

### Update

Shipment Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Shipment;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Origin;
use App\Employee;
use App\Equipment;
use App\Customer;
use App\Shipment_Type;
use App\Notifications\FreightBillNew;
use App\User;
use App\Shipment_Detail;
use App\Shipment_Details_Rate_Type;
use App\Shipment_Details_Piece_Type;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ShipmentController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index()
    {

        $shipments = Shipment::paginate(15);
        return view('shipments.index', compact('shipments'));
    }



    public function archive()
    {
        $shipments = Shipment::latest()->filter(request(['month', 'year']))->get();
//      $shipmentarchives = Shipment::shipmentarchives();

        return view('archives.shipments', compact('shipments', 'shipmentarchives'));
        }



//      $shipments = Shipment::latest()//new request
//          
//          
//          ->filter(request(['month', 'year']))//new request
//          ->get();//new request

//      $shipments = Shipment::latest();
//      
//      
//      if ($month = request('month')) {
//          $shipments->whereMonth('status_completed', Carbon::parse($month)->month);
//      
//      }
//      if ($year = request('year')) {
//          $shipments->whereYear('status_completed',$month);
//      
//      }
//      
//      $shipments = $shipments->get();

//      $shipmentarchives = Shipment::selectRaw('year(status_completed) year, monthname(status_completed) month, count(*) completed')
//          ->groupBy('year','month')
//          ->orderByRaw('min(status_completed) desc')
//          ->where('status', '=', 0)
//          ->get()
//          ->toArray();
//      
//      return view('archives.shipments', compact('shipments','shipmentarchives'));


    public function show(Shipment $shipment)
    {
//      $this->authorize('view', $shipment);

        $shipment_details = $shipment->shipment_details;

        return view('shipments.show', compact('shipment','shipment_details'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $origins = Customer::where('origin','1')->get();
        $billtypes = Shipment_Type::all();
        $ratetypes = Shipment_Details_Rate_Type::all();
        $piecetypes = Shipment_Details_Piece_Type::all();
        $tractors = Equipment::where('unit_type','1')->get();
        $trailers = Equipment::where('unit_type','2')->get();
        $drivers = Employee::all();
        $customers = Customer::orderBy('customer_name','ASC')->get();
        $shipto = Customer::pluck('company_name','id')->toArray();
        $shipfrom = Customer::pluck('company_name','id')->toArray();
        return view ('shipments.create', compact ('origins','drivers','tractors','trailers','customers','billtypes','ratetypes','piecetypes'));
    }
    public function store(Shipment $request)
    {

        $this->validate(request(), [

            'pro_number' => 'required',
            'shipment_origin' => 'required'

        ]);

        $user_id = Auth::id();

        $input = $request->all();

        //Save Initial Shipment Data
        $shipment = new Shipment();
        $shipment->pro_number = request('pro_number');
        $shipment->shipment_origin = request('shipment_origin');
        $shipment->date = request('date');
        $shipment->due_date = request('due_date');
        $shipment->tractor_id = request('tractor_id');
        $shipment->trailer_id = request('trailer_id');
        $shipment->driver_id = request('driver_id');
        $shipment->notes = request('notes');
        $shipment->shipper_no = request('shipper_no');
        $shipment->ship_to = request('ship_to');
        $shipment->ship_from = request('ship_from');
        $shipment->bill_to = request('bill_to');
        $shipment->bill_type = request('bill_type');
        $shipment->load_date = request('load_date');
        $shipment->shipment_status = 0;
        $shipment->created_by = $user_id;

        $shipment->save();

        //Save Shipment Details
//       $data = array();

        foreach ($request->get('shipment_details') as $shipmentDetails) {
            $shipmentDetail = new ShipmentDetail();
            $shipmentDetail->pieces_number = $shipmentDetails['piecesNumber'];
            $shipmentDetail->pieces_type = $shipmentDetails['piecesType'];
            $shipmentDetail->rate_type = $shipmentDetails['rateType'];
            $shipmentDetail->charge = $shipmentDetails['charge'];
            $shipmentDetail->weight = $shipmentDetails['weight'];
            $shipmentDetail->hazmat = $shipmentDetails['hazmat'];
            $shipmentDetail->description = $shipmentDetails['description'];

            $shipment->shipment_details()->save($shipment_detail);
            }
        //Return to Register
      return redirect('/shipments');

    }
}
```

Shipment Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shipment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'pro_number', 
        'shipment_origin',
        'notes',
        'shipment_status',
        'due_date',
        'date',
        'description',
        'driver_id',
        'tractor_id',
        'trailer_id',
        'shipper_no',
        'ship_to',
        'ship_from',
        'bill_to',
        'bill_type',
        'load_date'
    ];

    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class);
    }

    public function origin() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Origin', 'id','shipment_origin');
    }    
    public function shipment_details(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Shipment_Detail');
    }
}
```

Shipment_Detail Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class shipment_detail extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'shipment_id',
        'pieces_number',
        'pieces_type',
        'rate_type',
        'weight',
        'hazmat',
        'description',
        'charge'
    ];

    public function shipment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shipment');
    }
}
```

### Updated suggested change

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate(request(), [

            'pro_number' => 'required',
            'shipment_origin' => 'required'

        ]);

        $user_id = Auth::id();

        $input = $request->all();

        //Save Initial Shipment Data
        $shipment = new Shipment();
        $shipment->pro_number = request('pro_number');
        $shipment->shipment_origin = request('shipment_origin');
        $shipment->date = request('date');
        $shipment->due_date = request('due_date');
        $shipment->tractor_id = request('tractor_id');
        $shipment->trailer_id = request('trailer_id');
        $shipment->driver_id = request('driver_id');
        $shipment->notes = request('notes');
        $shipment->shipper_no = request('shipper_no');
        $shipment->ship_to = request('ship_to');
        $shipment->ship_from = request('ship_from');
        $shipment->bill_to = request('bill_to');
        $shipment->bill_type = request('bill_type');
        $shipment->load_date = request('load_date');
        $shipment->shipment_status = 0;
        $shipment->created_by = $user_id;

        $shipment->save();

        //Save Shipment Details
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($shipment_details); $i++) { 
            Shipment_Detail::create([ 
                'shipment_id' => $request->shipment_id, 
                'pieces_number' => $shipment_details['piecesNumber'][$i], 
                'pieces_type' => $shipment_details['piecesType'][$i],
                'rate_type' => $shipment_details['rateType'][$i],
                'charge' => $shipment_details['charge'][$i],
                'weight' => $shipment_details['weight'][$i],
                'hazmat' => $shipment_details['hazmat'][$i],
                'description' => $shipment_details['description'][$i] ]);
            }
        //Return to Register
      return redirect('/shipments');

    }
```

Comment: By the way, sidenote, you can save some line of codes if you make the relevant fields fillable in the model and use `$shipment = new Shipment($request->all())` also you don't have `$shipment_detail` declared anywhere, perhaps you need to do `$shipment_detail = new ShipmentDetail($request->get("shipment_details.<index>")`

Comment: What do you get if you dd($shipment_detail)?

Comment: @robbyrr - do you have a suggestion as to where to place that? For the life of me I have tried everywhere where I would normally place it (while also trying a variety of commenting out code). I believe the issue, based on where I placed the code and commented out others, that the issue lies somewhere beneath the $data = array(); line and the end of the foreach line. Because if I put the dd right after the foreach, my original error still pops up, and obviously before the $shipmentDetails is never mentioned so there is nothing to reference. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @robbyrr - I have updated the question with the post data so you can see that the only arrayed data should be shipment_details

Comment: @apokryfos - I have updated it with a mention that I've seen others do in this type of situation, though not entirely. As for the saving lines of code, it is my intent to pear it down, I just like to overexpand things to make sure they work right before I go slimming it down, just to readily see where an issue might arise.

Comment: what about dd($shipmentDetails) right after:  foreach ($request->get('shipment_details') as $shipmentDetails){ //here the dd($shipmentDetails)

Comment: @robbyrr - Unfortunately is still pulls out the same results... :/

Comment: hmm..And how does your table structure looks like, where you try to save shipment_details? And why are you type-hinting Shipment $request and not Request $request to obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection and acces the POST data ? because i cant see where you acces  the POST data except when you use the request() helper function . I'm just trying to understand things more clear

Comment: No I appreciate your help, this one perplexes me beyond reason. It doesn't help that I've been working off other examples to try and get to this point. I will update question in a few with some additional bits of information. The table it's trying to save to is a "child" table called shipment_details. I've posted my models and complete controller. As for the rest, I've been following the variety of examples to try and get me here. The problem I know with the controller arises in the foreach section where the shipment_details are saved in bulk.

Comment: What if you try this: Typehint Request like public function store(Request $request)  And then   for($i = 0; $i < count($shipment_details); $i++) {

            Shipment_Detail::create([
                'shipment_id' => $request->shipment_id,
                'pieces_number' => $shipment_details['piecesNumber'][$i],
                'pieces_type' => $shipment_details['piecesType'][$i]
            ]);

Comment: i only typed pieces_number and pieces_type, otherwise it would be a long and even uglier comment, but you get the idea..the rest is the same.. So instead of a foreach use this for loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159860/discussion-between-robbyrr-and-matthew).

Comment: By the way you've still not declared `$shipment_detail` anywhere in the code you shared

Comment: @apokryfos - that's next on the list but I was curious if you might have a suggestions as to where to put that. This array is perplexing me and I'm not entirely sure how to declare it with this form of submission (thank you so much for your help too!

Comment: I'd try `$shipment->shipment_details()->save($shipmentDetail)` and not refer to the other variable at all since it does not exist.

Comment: @apokryfos - I updated the controller based on some suggestions from robbyrr, so you can see it at the bottom of my question. Would your suggestion still work and where would you think about placing it? Thanks

Comment: In the shipment controller you have line `$shipment->shipment_details()->save($shipment_detail);` which will obviously not work because you have not defined `$shipment_detail` anywhere. I'm saying you should **replace** that line with `$shipment->shipment_details()->save($shipmentDetail);` because `$shipmentDetail` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code matthew and i came up with which works:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->shipment_details['piecesNumber']); $i++) {

    Shipment_Detail::create([
        'shipment_id' => $shipment->id,
        'pieces_number' => $request->shipment_details['piecesNumber'][$i],
        'pieces_type' => $request->shipment_details['piecesType'][$i],
        'rate_type' => $request->shipment_details['rateType'][$i],
        'charge' => $request->shipment_details['charge'][$i],
        'weight' => $request->shipment_details['weight'][$i],
        'hazmat' => $request->shipment_details['hazmat'][$i],
        'description' => $request->shipment_details['description'][$i] ]);
}
```